# How do I delete a VM from 'virsh list -all'?

Tags: virtualization, vmbuilder

I created a VM using `vmbuilder` but I realize that I had set some of the flags incorrectly. Now when I do a `virsh list -all` it still appears, laughing at my novicity. How do I delete this? (I've already deleted the corresponding xml and qcow2 files).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to delete a guest after creating it with virt-install](http://serverfault.com/questions/299632/how-to-delete-a-guest-after-creating-it-with-virt-install)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have already removed the disk image file, you can completely get rid of the VM with `virsh undefine <domain-id>`. You can also specify `--managed-save` to delete any managed save images and `--snapshots-metadata` to remove snapshots for the specified VM.

If the VM is in inactive state you should use its name or UUID instead of domain-id.