# Files left over after removing KVM guest

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu, virsh

Looking at [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/402647/how-do-i-delete-a-vm-from-virsh-list-all) I ran the following commands to remove a VM:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/libvirt/images/centos01.qcow2
sudo virsh undefine centos01 --managed-save --snapshots-metadata
```

But it looks like I still have some files pertaining to this image present:

```
find /var -name centos*
/var/log/libvirt/qemu/centos01.log
/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/centos01.monitor
```

Should I just delete these files? Will I run into a problem if I create a new VM with the same name?

Also, what is a .monitor file? I haven't been able to find much info about what they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files are safe to delete as long as the corresponding VM is not running.

The log files are never deleted automatically when you undefine a VM; you can rotate or delete them yourself.

And the monitor is a socket by which you can connect to the VM's internal [qemu monitor](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Monitor). Not somehting you need if the VM no longer exists, and you don't normally use it anyway.